# Powershell - send email html

Tags: html, email, powershell

I have a code which check free space on disk and send email for me with alert, but I want that email was in html. What i do wrong?

This is my code:

```
$html=
@'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .alert {{
    background-color: #FB1717 }}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>SystemName</th><th>DeviceID</th><th>VolumeName</th><th>Size(GB)</th><th>FreeSpace(GB)</th></tr>
{0}
</table>
</body></html>
'@

$entryTemplate = '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'
$alertEntryTemplate = '<tr class="alert"><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'


Function Get-ComInfo {   
param(
$computers

)

#Here LOW Space thresold is lessthan 10% of the total size of the Volume
$PercentFree = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace /1GB)}} 
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computers |
Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,$PercentFree,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={int}}

}

$entries = Get-Content U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\servers.txt | % { Get-ComInfo -computers $_ } | % {

    if ([float]::Parse($_.'FreeSpace(GB)') -le 5) {
        $alertEntryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
    }

    else {
        $entryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
    }

}

$html -f ($entries -join ' ') | out-file U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Drivess.htm

$EmailFrom = "xxx@xxx.com"
$EmailTo = "xxx@xxx.com" 
$Subject = "$computers DISK ISSUE DETECTED"  
$SMTPServer = "smtp.xxx.com" 
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage  
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX"); 
$MailTextT =  Get-Content  -Path U:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Drivess.htm 
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$msg.Body = $MailTextT | ConvertTo-Html
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $MailTextT)
```

I get such a result in the email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>HTML TABLE</title>  <style type="text/css">   .alert {     background-color: #FB1717 }   </style> </head> <body> <table> <colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup> <tr><th>SystemName</th><th>DeviceID</th><th>VolumeName</th><th>Size(GB)</th><th>FreeSpace(GB)</th></tr> <tr><td>K005</td><td>C:</td><td></td><td>76,5</td><td>111,0</td><td></td><td></td></tr> <tr><td>K005</td><td>U:</td><td>Nowy</td><td>87,4</td><td>465,8</td><td></td><td></td></tr> </table> </body></html>
```

And not is converted to html, I dont know why? I try converted to html  `$msg.Body = $MailTextT | ConvertTo-Html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the ConvertTo-Html on the text here as you've allready formatted your text.

Just use your html text directly (And read the contents as a whole using -raw):

```
$MailTextT =  Get-Content  -Path U:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Drivess.htm -Raw
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$msg.Body = $MailTextT
```

Comment: `-Raw` not working. Again is it same. Email it`s not converted to html. But, thx for answer :)

Comment: You email is sent correctly though. Then I'm assuming it's a html-formatting issue as it's very limited on what you can to with html in an email. Check your formatting and the common pitfalls: http://www.benchmarkemail.com/help-FAQ/answer/Common-HTML-Email-Coding-Mistakes and this link: https://litmus.com/blog/16-tips-troubleshooting-html-email . They should help you troubleshoot your formatting.

Comment: It seems to me that everything is ok, but I could be wrong because I have little experience with html . Maybe does anyone have any other ideas ? I look all the time other codes , and trying new ideas but still the same. I sent a email to gmail , but it does not work.

Comment: Ok, I was able to do it. I add: `$OutputFile = "U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Drivess.html" $MailTextT =  Get-Content  -Path U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Drivess.html -Raw
$msg = New-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $body)
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true  
$SMTPClient.Send($msg)` Thx for help!